# Doctrine2 association persist slow as hell

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `while` loop in where I create the main entity `Order`, this entity has a lot of fields and associations but persists fast, very fast.

But it as a  `oneToMany` unidirectional (`manyToMany`) association, which takes forever... This association is small, only two fields so I don't know why it takes so long.

I have an array of `$items`, exactly 17 items. Inside the while loop, foreach `Order` I add theese 17 items inside the assoc.

```
while($i < 53000)
{
    // ... 
    foreach($item as $k => $v)
    {
        $item = new Item();
        $item->setName($v['name']);
        $item->setValue($order[$v['column']]);

        $order->addItem($item);
    }

    // ...

    $em->persist($order);

    $i++;
    if($i % 200 == 0) // I've tried multiples values in here but everything is slow.
    {
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear(); // Commenting this, doesn't speed up things neither.
    }
}
```

Of course I know that for every `Order`there are 17 `Item` created, but as `Item` object is so small, I don't think it needs to take that long...

With the `Item` `forEach`, it takes about 35 minutes to end the script. If I remove that, the script only takes 4 minutes to run, which is ridiculous...

The relation mapping is as follows

```
  manyToMany:
    items:
      targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Item
      cascade: ["all"]
      joinTable:
        name: order_has_item
        joinColumns:
          product_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          item_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
```

It is unidirectional so no mapping for `Item` is created.

Answer (score 3):

You're generating 53000 `Order`s, of which each has (as you say) around 17 `Item`s. That's 954000 database entries being generated.

You're persisting every 200 `Order`s, so each call to `$em->persist()` creates 3600 entity objects and DB entries.

There are, at least, two performance hits:

1. Doctrine will generate 3600 entities with all bells and whistles.
2. The database indices of the affected tables are updated on each insert.

Also, don't forget that if you're doing this in the `dev` environment, Symfony will log an ass-load of stuff (see `app/logs/dev.log`) and has several debugging features on.

So, how can you shove nearly a million entries into your DB? Doctrine is unfortunately very bad at *really* bulk operations. It is usually a better to use a native SQL query (though, sacrificing portability … but who cares, anyway):

```
$em->getConnection()->executeUpdate(/*INSERT etc. …*/);
```

When inserting objects that relate to each other, it's a bit more difficult, because we must ensure consistency:

```
try
{
    $conn = $em->getConnection();
    $conn->beginTransaction();

    foreach ($orders as $order)
    {
        $conn->executeUpdate(/*INSERT the order …*/);
        $orderId = $conn->lastInsertId();

        foreach ($order->items as $item)
        {
            $item->orderId = $orderId;
            $conn->executeUpdate(/*INSERT the item …*/);
        }
    }

    $conn->commit();
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
    $conn->rollback();
    throw $e;
}

// NOTE: the try/catch wraps *all* orders, so if one order fails *no* 
// orders will be saved. Alternatively, put the try/catch into the loop
```

(I kept the code short for readability, you'll get the idea. Not tested, just from the top of my head.)

Have a look at the [Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#executeupdate) to learn more about native queries.

---

By the way, in your example, if you only write to the DB when `($i % 200 == 0)`, you're going to loose your `($i % 200)` last items. You'd need to write something like:

```
$amount = 53000;

while($i < $amount)
{
    // do your thing

    $i++;

    if($i % 200 === 0 || $i >= $amount)
    {
        // flush/clear
    }
}
```

Comment: I will test your things. By the way, after the while I do a last $em->flish() so the last items are being saved.

Comment: Link to Doctrine Documentation just goes to a "Not Found" page.